# How to parse int from String

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I have to keep inputting x and y coordinates, until the user inputs *"stop"*. However, I don't understand how to parse the input from `String` to `int`, as whenever I do, I get back errors.

```
public class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter x:");
            String x = kb.nextLine();

            if (x.equals("stop")) {
                System.out.println("Stop");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Enter y:");
            String y = kb.nextLine();

            if (y.equals("stop")) {
                System.out.println("Stop"); }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(x)` - but this will throw an exception if the value is not a integer value

Comment: Title is inadequate to the content: should be "parse this string"

Answer (score 1):

To Parse integer from `String` you can use this code snippet.

```
    try{

     int    xx = Integer.parseInt(x);
     int    yy = Integer.parseInt(y);

        //Do whatever want
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Error please input integer.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice way to do this in my opinion is to always read the input as a string and then test if it can be converted to an integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            String input;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter x:");
            input = kb.nextLine();

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
                System.out.println("Stop");
                break;
            }

            try {
                x = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println(x);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("No valid number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot

Answer (score 0):

With

```
String variablename = Integer.toString(x);
```

Comment: This won't work; [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) requires an `int`, not a `String`.

Comment: ok, int xx = Integer.parseInt(x); and String variablename = Integer.toString(xx);  if(variablename.equals("stop")){...

Comment: Then why go through the trouble of converting the `String` to an `int` and back? Besides, assuming `Integer.parseInt` does not throw an exception, the resultant string will never not be a number, so `variableName.equals("stop")` will always return false.